# UTF-8 characters display differently after import to mySQL

Tags: mysql, utf-8, load-data-infile, ms-access-2010

I have a mySQL database full of accented characters.  The DB is populated periodically from MS Access 2010.

In Access you'll see é è à Ü.  In the export process in Access UTF-8 encoding is specified.

Open the resulting text file in UltraEdit on my PC and you'll see "Vieux Carré" and UE says the encoding is U8-DOS.

The files are uploaded via FTP and imported via LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE queries like this

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$dir/$t.$ext' INTO TABLE `$t` FIELDS  OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '|' TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

In mySQL the field collation is set to utf8_general_ci.

If you query mySQL from the command line or from phpMyAdmin you'll see "Vieux CarrÃ©".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `LOAD DATA INFILE` with a file that has a charset that's different from your *database's* default, you need to specify what character set the file is in:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$dir/$t.$ext'
INTO TABLE `$t`
CHARACTER SET utf8
FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '|' TERMINATED BY ';'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Note that the database character set is database-wide, and is different than the *table* character set and the *column* character set. `SHOW CREATE DATABASE database_name` will show you the database charset.

Comment: Man I could kiss you.  Next time you are in New Orleans I owe you a sammich!